# Windows 10 Search after first press of Control-Escape not working, Cortana disabled in policy/registry

Tags: windows, autohotkey

This is a unique problem I have and I've searched and am unable to find a solution. This is on Windows 10, with latest updates, as of up to 9/28/2017, for the past few months. I have disabled Cortana via registry and policy. If after using system for a bit (say, 10+ seconds), and I hit Control-Escape, it brings up the start menu. Search never works. I'm a touch typist so this is really annoying. I want to hit Control-Escape and start typing my search, which works fine on other people's computers.

For example, to run cmd.exe, my typing is "Control-Esc,c,m,d,Enter". On my system, search doesn't come up and my c,m,d keystrokes don't go anywhere. I have to wait a second, then redo this, and it will work. I don't have a Run key, and I'm really used to this Control-Escape, then start typing method, and ideally would like to keep using it.

One "solution" I've found is that if I taskkill Cortana, it stays killed for a bit (like 10-15 seconds?), then comes back. If I taskkill Cortana, then hit control-esc within a few seconds, search always works. My temporary "solution" is to use auto-hotkey, and this script:

```
^Esc::
    Process,Close,SearchUI.exe
    KeyWait Esc
    KeyWait Ctrl
    Send {LWin}
Return
```

This intercepts the control-esc sequence, and kills Cortana instead, then waits until control and escape keys are released, then presses windows key (found this tip in another stackoverflow question/answer).

Anyone have any other ideas how to fix this, or what causes it? My guess is Cortana is somehow trying to do something and it's timing causes search to fail. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that this is going about the problem the wrong way. If changes to the registry and policy have broken Windows application search, I would revert the changes and troubleshoot from there. There are a number of places that walk through disabling Cortana on Windows, and there's no mention of lost functionality in Search. AutoHotkey at this point would be a band-aid.